# How to create a API scope using Azure AD Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Azure AD Graph API to create an API Scope for an Azure AD B2C application. This is the operation performed using the "Expose an API" blade in the portal.

I've tried adding the scope directly to the application like so:

```
var current = await graphClient.Applications[appId].Request().GetAsync();
var currentList = current.Api.Oauth2PermissionScopes ?? new List<PermissionScope>();
var newScope = new PermissionScope
{
    AdminConsentDescription = scopeDescription,
    AdminConsentDisplayName = scopeDescription,
    IsEnabled = true,
    Type = "Admin",
    Value = scopeName
};
var updated = new Application { 
    Api = new ApiApplication { 
        Oauth2PermissionScopes = currentList.Append(newScope).ToList() 
    } 
};
await graphClient.Applications[appId].Request().UpdateAsync(updated);
```

However, when I do that, I get an exception:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
> Code: ValueRequired
> Message: Property api.oauth2PermissionScopes.id value is required but is empty or missing.

Does this mean that I need to create the scope separately then add it to the application? Looking over the Graph API docs, it isn't obvious how to do that and I haven't found any articles that discuss it, either.

How do you use Graph API to create API scopes?

Comment: According to the error, when we  define `PermissionScope` object, we need to provide property `id` (it is GUID). For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permissionscope?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to  use the Microsoft Graph API to create an API Scope for an Azure AD B2C application, we need to define `PermissionScope` object. The object should provide `id`(it is GUID).

For example

1. [Register Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-management-application)
2. Grant API permissions

   - Under **Manage**, select **API permissions**.
   - Under **Configured permissions**, select **Add a permission**.
   - Select the **Microsoft APIs tab**, then select **Microsoft Graph**.
   - Select **Application permissions**.
   - Select the checkbox of the permission **Application.ReadWrite.All** to grant to your application.
   - Select **Add permissions**. As directed, wait a few minutes before proceeding to the next step.
   - Select **Grant admin consent for (your tenant name)**.
3. Create a client secret
4. code

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string clientId = "0159ec7d-f99f-***";
            string clientSecret = "G_fM3QKa***essTRX23t1_o";
            string tenantDomain = "{your tenat name}.onmicrosoft.com";

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(clientId)
                        .WithTenantId(tenantDomain)
                        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                        .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            var id = "fa89ac50-d5fd-47cb-9f3f-833f413a2ed4";
            var app =await graphClient.Applications[id].Request().GetAsync();
            var updated = new Application();
            if (app.IdentifierUris.ToList().Count == 0) {
                updated.IdentifierUris = new string[] { $"https://{tenantDomain}/{app.AppId}" };
            }

            var appscope = app.Api.Oauth2PermissionScopes.ToList();
            var newScope = new PermissionScope
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                AdminConsentDescription = "Allow the application to have read-only access to all Employee data",
                AdminConsentDisplayName = "Read-only access to Employee records",
                IsEnabled = true,
                Type = "Admin",
                Value = "Employees.Read.All"
            };
            appscope.Add(newScope);
            updated.Api = new ApiApplication { Oauth2PermissionScopes =appscope };
            await graphClient.Applications[id].Request().UpdateAsync(updated);


        }
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permissionscope?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: That worked, thanks. I didn't think of trying that since Azure had complained when I assigned the ID property when creating other objects (e.g., Application). So much for consistency.